# OepnDJ - Automatically create user data directory

Tags: ldap, opendj

I'm using OpenDJ to manage (create, search, delete) my user account. However, I would like to know how to create user data directory (e.g. /data/sam/file/)  for user in advance once the account is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own OpenDJ plugin (post Add / Modify operation) to create the directory based on the attribute value. Please check the Server Plugin javadoc for reference : http://docs.forgerock.org/en/opendj/2.6.0/javadoc/index.html